# I can not associate my fully active AdSense account with my YouTube channel

Tags: youtube, adsense

I have an AdSense account even I have earnings which comes from my Android applications I can see them under the Admob tab. Bu what I don't understand whenever I try to associate my AdSense account with my YouTube channel it gives me this error:

**You are currently signed into the Google Account *******@gmail.com, which is either not an active AdSense account, or still pending an approval. This account cannot be used to monetize your content.**

I really don't understand why I get this. I have an absolutely active AdSense account using the same gmail with my YouTube channel which is getting denied by the error you see above. I did even received a letter from Google 4 months ago which had a PIN in it so that I could approve my billing address.

Please help me understand what am I doing wrong here.

Many Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You could check if your account is active by login in to adsense's main site.

That might help you know whats wrong

https://www.google.com/adsense/

Answer (score 0):

For me I just had to go to my AdSense Dashboard

In the left menu go to "My Ads" -> "Other products"

Then follow the connect your website steps

I didn't want to connect my website but this is what enabled my AdSense account to work with YouTube; it appears YouTube connects in a similar way by using your channel URL to associate the accounts